# Usar tag html para substituir componentes do JSF, quando possivel

Tags: html, jsf, xhtml

Estou iniciando os estudos com JSF (JavaServer Faces) e escrevendo um arquivo xhtml, me surgiu o seguinte dilema:

Porque não usar tag do HTML substituindo algums componete do JSF, quando possivel?
Exemplo: usar: `<label for="nome">Nome</label>` ao invés de `<h:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome"/>`

Essa prática melhora o desempenho da aplicação, já o servidor terá menos componentes para processar, ou não faz diferença, já que todos as tags serão processadas pelo servidor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode sim utilizar tags HTML e JSF na mesma página. A vantagem de usar os componentes JSF é que você pode acessa-los pela arvore de componentes JSF. Com as tags HTML você não pode.

Referências:

[Mixing JSF Tag and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7418873/5165064)

[JSF/Facelets: why is it not a good idea to mix JSF/Facelets with HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7320873/5165064)

Comment: Ok @Rafael, boa observação. Grato pelas referencias, dessa formar pude entender melhor sobre o assunto.